# Replace word depending on the regex search result

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to figure out regex. I'm fairly new to it and am wondering if I can do the following with just a few lines of code. I'm trying to avoid using a switch statement here so I came up with the idea of doing the following:

First off, let me explain what this will do: Get a string and replace keys with a variable already existing locally in the method. Something like this:

```
var a = 'item a',
    b = 'item b',
    string = '@a@ and @b@ have been replaced!',
    regex = /\@[a|b]\@/g;

 //now somehow replace this conditionally

 return string.replace(regex, this[replacerResut]);
```

And the output would be this:
`item a and item b have been replaced!`

Not sure if it's possible, but would love to know a way of doing it. there is more than two local variables so you can see why I wouldn't want to use a switch, and the rookie in me says that's what I would do! So I know it's wrong. I'm trying write polymorphic code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If `a`, `b`, etc. have to be variables rather than arrays there is no way because there are no variable-variables in JS.  If they can be an array/object values, it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, since Javascript `String#replace` supports callbacks, but you should collect the replacements to one object (getting the value of `var a` knowing `"a"` is not possible to do in a clean way):

```
var replacement={
      a : 'item a',
      b : 'item b'
    },
    string = '@a@ and @b@ have been replaced!',
    regex = /\@([ab])\@/g; //note the added capturing group


 return string.replace(regex, function(whole, key){
   return replacement[key];
 });
```

alternatively:

```
var a = 'item a',
    b = 'item b',
    string = '@a@ and @b@ have been replaced!',
    regex = /\@[ab]\@/g; 


 var replacement = {"@a@":a, "@b@":b};
 return string.replace(regex, function(whole){
   return replacement[whole];
 });
```

---

side note:

Your regex `@[a|b]@` will match `@a@` and `@b@`, but also `@|@`. Either use alternation (`@(a|b)@`, or a character group (`@[ab]@`). Don't confuse them together.

Comment: Jan you the man! Thank you very much for your help man. I ended up going with with your first suggestion! Just did a minor change in the replace whole part `return replacement[whole.replace(/@/g, '')];` To clean out the `@` I kept getting an undefined then realized it was looking for a var with `replacement[@a@]`I couldn't have done it without you friend! Thanks again!

Comment: The first version does not look for `replacement["a"]`. I've just checked. The second version does, but I've accounted for that.

Answer (score 2):

Jan Dvorak's answer is the way forward. Just as an appendix, the code provided by him could be made even *"cleaner"*, by using the replacement object a closure object, so it can be GC'ed after the `replace` call returns:

```
string.replace(expression, (function()
{
    var replacement = {a: 'item a',
                       b: 'item b'};
    return function(match)
    {//the actual callback
        return replacement[match];
    };
}()));//IIFE
//console.log(replacement);//undefined, can't be referenced anymore and may be flagged for GC
```

You needn't take it this far, but just so you know: even though you can't do actual memory management in JS, you can influence the flag & sweep Garbage collector by means of closures and scopes...

Comment: I was expecting the initial scope was reasonable enough so that namespace clutter wouldn't happen. Also, if the replacement object is this small, I'm not worried about memory usage. Still a good note if the replacement object could be huge and you only do the replacement once (you might want to avoid recreating the object multiple times).

Comment: @JanDvorak: I agree with you, I didn't mean to present this closure-approach as the _"better"_ alternative here, far from it. Yours is the one I voted for. As you say, if the replacement object is huge, this approach can give you some form of control over the memory management.

Comment: Scratch my comment about not being a closure. I didn't notice the replacemenent object's scope is an IIFE. Somehow I hate IIFEs returning anything.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Ah, well... I _love_ that :). Personal preference, I guess... Module pattern, closures, love them, though I must admit, sometimes code does get less maintainable if you _"forget"_ to document everything :)

Comment: I guess I'll have to stop forgetting what the "E" in "IIFE" means :-)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done if they are not local variables using `window` (although I would call this evil):

```
string.replace(regex, function (match, group) {
    return window[group];
});
```

Put them in an object with the string matches as the keys and the replacements as values if you can.

I recommend this regex:

```
regex = /@(\w+?)@/g;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4uvW/

Comment: It can be done even with local variables, but it's still evil (more evil than `window[group]`)

Comment: Ahem. First you suggest using `window[group]`, then you suggest `/@(\w+?)@/`. Are you sure you want to make all global variables egligible for replacement to the string?

Comment: Also note that this won't work outside of a browser environment. If you want to be more generic, you could capture the global `this`: `var global = this`

Comment: @JanDvorak woah, slow down.  I said it was evil; he should really use an object or an array.  Using `window[group]` as I described are not mutually exclusive at all.  Please read my answer carefully.  Note how there is variable `regex` in the `replace` method.  What do you think that is supposed to be?